# Windows service for WCF Stops

Tags: windows, wcf, exception, service

I have a WCF application hosted as a windows service. This windows service triggers this WCF every 15 minutes. But when an exception occurs in this WCF the service is getting stopped.

I don't want this service to stop. I want to some how handle this exception and trigger this WCF after another 15 minutes.

Comment: what do you mean when you say the windows service triggers the WCF service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle exceptions in all your service operations in order to:

- Return nice faults to the caller
- Prevent the service from failing miserably

Put a try/catch around every operation or use a custom behavior to handle all exceptions coming from your service

Answer (score 1):

Look for the `ServiceHost.Open(...)` and put a try/catch around it perhaps.

Comment: ServiceHost.Open is a non-blocking operation, which means it'll open it, then exit, thus making the try/catch block redundant.

Comment: I was having a problem where execution just stopped on ServiceHost.Open ... Putting a try/catch around it actually did, bizarrely enough, reveal an exception. Still puzzling this out.